# NodeJS POST request returning bad JSON error, but is it?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to call Google NEST API for the thermostat, but I'm getting the following error:

```
{
    "error": {
      "code": 400,
      "message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"params[heatCelsius]\": Cannot bind query parameter. Field 'params[heatCelsius]' could not be found in request message.",
      "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
      "details": [
        {
          "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest",
          "fieldViolations": [
            {
              "description": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"params[heatCelsius]\": Cannot bind query parameter. Field 'params[heatCelsius]' could not be found in request message."
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Here is how I am creating the post data:

```
    var temp = req.query.temp;
    var coolOrHeat = req.query.coolHeat;

    let celsius = (temp - 32) * 5 / 9;

    var jsonDataObj;

    if (coolOrHeat == "heat") {
        jsonDataObj = {
            command: 'sdm.devices.commands.ThermostatTemperatureSetpoint.SetHeat',
            params: {
                heatCelsius: celsius
            }
        }
    }

    if (coolOrHeat == "cool") {
        jsonDataObj = {
            command: 'sdm.devices.commands.ThermostatTemperatureSetpoint.SetCool',
            params: {
                coolCelsius: celsius
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is my POST req:

```
            var urlSetTemp = 'https://smartdevicemanagement.googleapis.com/v1/enterprises/' + projectId + '/devices/' + thermId + ':executeCommand';

            request.post({
                headers: {
                    'content-type': 'application/json',
                    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken
                },
                form: jsonDataObj,
                url: urlSetTemp
            }, function (error, response, body) {

                var json = JSON.parse(body);
                console.log("res: ", json);


                res.json({
                    'json': json,
                    'ack': "success",
                    'body': jsonDataObj
                });
            });
```

Google's doc: https://developers.google.com/nest/device-access/traits/device/thermostat-temperature-setpoint#setheat

Finally, in Postman, it's good, it works, but not in Node.

What exactly am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: What is `request.post`? Why do you use the property `form` for the data? The error message looks like you're sending form data.

Comment: its a node module. const request = require('request');

Comment: Why did you remove this important detail from your code? Please read [mcve]. Why do you use a package that was deprecated 4 years ago? It looks like the default type is application/x-www-form-urlencoded and the `form` property is for form data. I can't find how to send raw JSON without a form. Does this package even support it? Why do you need this package?

Comment: i was able to figure it out. no reason why im using it, first one i saw. its a bradn new project for me, so looks like ill rewrite my node code with a non-deprecated package. any suggestions?

Comment: Use the native [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch). It's supported since Node.js v18. No package required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working for me now. I set body instead of form, and used JSON.stringify as well as setting JSON to true.

```
         request.post({
                headers: {
                    'content-type': 'application/json',
                    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(jsonDataObj),
                json: true,
                url: urlSetTemp
            }, function (error, response, body) {

                var json = JSON.parse(body);
                console.log("res: ", json);


                res.json({
                    'json': json,
                    'ack': "success",
                    'body': jsonDataObj
                });
            });
```